# how to pass data from table row in PHP to another page on click the table row

Tags: php

[SEE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTFHt.jpg)
table shows final output. So i want the user to be able to click on the BlockName field and on click the data at BlockName should be sent to another page.
                
                
                     </th> -->
                    title
                    initials
                    surname
                    phone
                    email
                    office
                    BlockName
                    department
                    photo
                
                ";

```
                 $index = 0;

               $querynum ="SELECT csi315_dir_staff.title,csi315_dir_staff.initials,csi315_dir_staff.surname,csi315_dir_staff.phone,csi315_dir_staff.BlockName,csi315_dir_staff.email,csi315_dir_staff.office,csi315_dir_departments.department_name, csi315_dir_staff.photo FROM csi315_dir_staff, csi315_dir_departments WHERE csi315_dir_staff.department_id=csi315_dir_departments.department_id AND $search_query";
               $resultnum = mysqli_query($db_link,$querynum);

              $num_members = mysqli_num_rows($resultnum);
             // echo "search for  $search_name :" ;
              echo " $num_members staff  found. ";

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $image="";
                if(file_exists("profile_pics/".$row['photo']))
                {
                    $image="profile_pics/".$row['photo'];
                }
                else{
                    $image="profile_pics/default.jpg";
                }   

                 echo "<tr  echo $index++ % 2 ? ' class='even'' : ''>",
                "<td>{$row['title']} </td>",
                "<td>{$row['initials']}</td>",
                "<td>{$row['surname']}</td>",
                "<td>{$row['phone']}</td>",
                "<td>{$row['email']}</td>",
                "<td>{$row['office']}</td>",
                "<td>{$row['department_name']}</td>",
                "<td><a href =\"/phonebook/withDropdownList_version2/home.html?id={$row['BlockName']}\"/><img src=\"images/build.png\" width=25px\" height=\"25px\"/></a>&nbsp;</td>",
                "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</tbody>
            </table>";

            // render the pagination links
            $pagination->render();`
```

Comment: Your question has several problems. a) it's too broad, b) you're not actually asking anything, c) you're posting extremely messy code without explaining the context, d) the text above your question has no structure and is not understandable like that.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: All you have to do is add any data you want to pass to the `home.html` on the querystring like you have done with the `BloclName` here `home.html?id={$row['BlockName']}`

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as query parameters.